# Roslyn semantic analysis

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a big problem with Roslyn.NET CTP and semantic analysis my code.
My task is: get classdeclaration and his inherited type.
For example:
Class: Change : ChangePassword
I must write in console: "ChangePassword" type name.
How can I do this? In reflection is very simple: (this is a generic type):

```
foreach (Type t in types)
        {
            if (t.BaseType.IsGenericType)
            {
                Type[] typeArguments = t.BaseType.GetGenericArguments();

                foreach (Type tParam in typeArguments)
                {
                    typesList.Add(tParam.Name);
                    typesListProperties = tParam.GetProperties();

                    foreach (var p in typesListProperties)
                        typesListPropertiesList.Add(p.Name);                     
                }

            }

        }
```

But I my problem requires the use roslyn.
My idea is use semanticModel.GetTypeInfo or GetSymbolInfo but none of them accepts a parameter SyntaxNode!

My reality class declaration is:

```
public partial class Example : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<ExampleModel>
```

for this example I must add to `List<string>` "ExampleModel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at using `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(ClassDeclarationSyntax)` to determine the `Symbol` for your type, then inspect the `BaseType` property.